# URL bar not updated in Chrome after Backbone routing

Tags: google-chrome, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I have a Backbone application which, at one point, opens a new tab in the browser. After the execution in the new tab is complete a javascript will be triggered (in that new tab) to trigger routing in the opener window. Javascript code looks like this:

```
window.onunload  = window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
                    opener.router.navigate("start",{trigger: true});
                };
window.close();
```

This works great, the 'start' route is executed and the correct result is shown in all browsers (including Chrome). But in Chrome, the url bar is not updated with the new url (eg. ../something#start), instead the original url for the opening window remains in the address bar.

In IE and Firefox the url bar shows the correct url. Is there some way to achieve this behaviour in Chrome also?

Any input appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to make a call to the router directly from the tab that's about to be closed, have you tried triggering a Backbone event (which the "opener window" would be listening to) instead?

So change:

```
window.onunload  = window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
    opener.router.navigate("start",{trigger: true});
};
window.close();
```

to:

```
window.onunload  = window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
    Backbone.trigger('routeChange');
};
window.close();
```

And include a listener to the `routeChange` event in the "opener window's" view with a callback function which executes `router.navigate()`:

```
opener.listenTo(Backbone, 'routeChange', function(e) {
    opener.router.navigate('start',{trigger: true});
});
```

Let me know if that helps.